# F# Game Development

Tags: cross-platform, .net

I'm a [F#](http://fsharp.net/) user. What library should I use to develop games (2D and/or 3D) in F# and being cross-platform? Like how [Processing](http://processing.org) is.

Don't answer DirectX or WPF or other things that are "too .NET" because they are not cross-platform.

Show me a library suggestion and a code example and a link to help me to get started in your answer.

Comment: This question would probably be better titled "Cross Platform .NET Game/Graphics Library".

Comment: I'm usually all for directness but I think a little bit of politeness wouldn't kill... anyway: I fully support using OpenTK.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com/) has OpenGL and OpenGL ES bindings and works well with F# on .NET and Mono

Comment: code example - http://laurent.le-brun.eu/fsharp/opengl.fs

Comment: You can use OpenTK alongside various windowing methods - such as Windows Form or GTK. WinForms is pretty mature on Mono.